# how to download csv with fusion charts in codeigniter

Tags: csv, fusioncharts

I have been trying below function to generate CSV for download, but what I am seeing is that I can get CSV data only in `alert`.

```
function ExportMyChart(type) {
    var chartObj = getChartFromId('myChartIdAmount4');
    if( chartObj.hasRendered() ){
        if(type === 'CSV'){  
            alert(chartObj.getDataAsCSV());
        }else{
            chartObj.exportChart({ exportAtClient: '1',  exportFormat: type, exportAction: 'download' }); 
        }
    }
}
```

`chartObj.exportChart` is not working for CSV, is there any way i can make it work for CSV as it work for PDF, JPEG ?. I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: am not sure your logic (as per the above code) is to fire alert when the type is CSV. So when it is csv the else condition will not execute. Am I missing anything?

Comment: `if(type ==='CSV')` because `chartObj.exportChart({ exportAtClient: '1',  exportFormat: type, exportAction: 'download' });` gives error if I use it for CSV

Comment: exportChart and getDataAsCSV is completely separate methods for separate purpose.[read](http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/features/#exporting-as-images-or-pdf)

Comment: and somehow `exportChart` fails to work with CSV, any thought why is it so

Comment: It is because exporting is made for image or PDF formats. CSV is not an export format, it is simply getting data from chart as CSV string.

Comment: @Nishikant that is what I exactly wanted to explain. :)

Comment: BTW there is nothing to do with CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export your CSV as a downloadable file by encoding the CSV string and by using download methods for createElement anchor tag object. See the code below which is a slight modification to your implementation.

See my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhargav3/eq9aC/3/) which uses FusionCharts V 3.3.1

```
var exportMyChart = function (type) {
    var chartObj = FusionCharts('myChartIdAmount4');

    if (chartObj.hasRendered()) {
        if(type === 'CSV'){  
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + encodeURIComponent(chartObj.getDataAsCSV());
            a.target = '_blank';
            a.download = 'export.csv';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
        }
        else{
            chartObj.exportChart({ exportAtClient: '1',  exportFormat: type, exportAction: 'download' });
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("What are you trying to export?");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did saved lots of time.

Answer (score 0):

Nishikant,

FusionCharts does not support CSV data as a downloadable option as it does with exporting of images/pdf.

So instead of showing the CSV in alert window you can store it in a variable then you can POST this to your server side handler (you'll have to create it) which will return it as CSV file.