# How do I create and write to a new file (csv) and have the browser download it with javascript or D3.js?

Tags: javascript, file, csv, d3.js

I have a website where users can view graphs with certain data that they choose. I want to include the functionality that lets the user get the data used for the data in a csv file preferably.

I have "ready'd" my data by sorting it in an array with this format:

(This is just an example of an output if the array was printed in the console.)

```
"CCL5,t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),t(15;17),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),inv(16)/t(16;16),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(8;21),t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,t(11q23)/MLL,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,complex ab. karyotype,HSC,HSC,HSC,HSC,HSC,HSC,MPP,MPP,CMP,CMP,CMP,GMP,GMP,GMP,GMP,GMP,GMP,GMP,MEP,MEP,MEP,MEP,early_PM,early_PM,early_PM,late_PM,late_PM,late_PM,MY,MY,MM,MM,MM,BC,BC,BC,BC,PMN,PMN,PMN,Mono,Mono,Mono,Mono"
"1555759_a_at,6.482143,6.956962,5.842203,6.635454,8.351578,6.719902,5.550186,8.386389,7.195372,8.260547,8.427704,8.822335,6.862085,7.512237,8.985445,8.196036,5.756727,6.386092,6.081735,6.864839,7.182530,7.425995,7.585837,6.726644,5.855473,6.620362,6.911726,6.641145,7.140018,7.239117,5.755348,7.115750,7.254431,7.054359,7.830496,6.757393,7.667946,6.980532,5.902994,7.299082,7.722713,7.419591,9.778600,8.039503,7.263772,6.340856,7.162263,8.067221,7.172460,6.077173,8.991111,5.661114,9.638651,8.878150,7.620753,5.602015,8.488841,8.193242,7.969061,7.168992,8.116956,7.786195,8.487662,7.833534,7.213922,8.085212,7.903602,6.929296,6.390902,7.769445,6.608767,8.722462,7.486884,8.981732,6.629700,6.289574,6.926666,7.012284,7.274458,7.104112,6.763590,7.401222,7.542741,6.751496,6.415097,6.921177,7.244994,6.915105,8.733037,7.775979,6.703853,7.613614,8.361467,7.544937,8.160733,7.902190,7.943476,7.915155,7.819592,8.060850,9.113587,7.236796,7.964187,8.295199,8.086927,7.406500,7.518251,8.621223,8.064387,7.459142,8.791649,9.367919,6.805781,6.579196,7.519587,7.927283,7.656491,8.832018,8.344374,8.195767,8.154316,8.374466,8.628794,8.737380,8.034807,7.471497,6.949001,6.435166,8.450038,6.004613,9.554797,8.290161,9.088501,9.303174,7.160714,9.649978,8.960903,8.642866,9.455499,9.169063,7.765629,8.897696,6.375738,7.506449,8.453261,9.148484,9.557149,8.890534,6.422878,7.631849,8.436778,8.213594,10.05178,8.241344,7.463228,8.457176,9.866300,6.387710,6.452311,7.688277,7.326702,8.879339,10.08454,9.366947,10.48616,7.725666,9.658422,8.225099,6.317467,11.77262,10.42063,8.190103,9.759814,7.090827,11.32362,6.575901,9.104124,10.98599,9.730232,8.675855,8.940791,6.778648,8.616864,9.037348,7.249411,7.615455,11.50930,9.142133,6.268137,9.399649,11.15425,9.707358,9.973163,7.953864,9.598833,8.871507,12.09951,7.277103,6.804820,7.715709,8.564474,6.877368,7.613922,8.524902,8.804725,7.848064,7.961819,9.873879,9.881986,11.22732,7.137895,8.889161,7.516756,8.271140,8.812730,10.82330,7.532594,8.269583,9.449080,9.026222,10.91917,7.645270,9.661588,7.861707,7.452133,9.459665,5.595994,10.53286,8.075182,7.071983,8.122966,7.106455,6.947456,11.30188,7.109542,8.195790,9.763742,7.753196,9.011795,7.345915,9.842569,7.648024,7.459603,8.327268,8.998685,9.126484,8.218383,9.878115,8.470798,8.122966,6.858914,6.945879,4.416836,4.782380,5.313776,5.383624,3.902351,5.534545,5.149230,4.965121,4.778415,4.945832,5.021578,5.617244,5.789978,4.535487,5.062555,5.893881,5.504087,5.004556,4.725728,4.478037,4.639980,4.787633,6.250180,7.080666,6.057337,6.828539,7.824775,6.125071,6.235946,5.060427,4.601436,5.119143,4.844748,5.281926,5.288049,5.297983,5.228851,5.160359,6.178164,5.382761,5.566544,5.839154,5.471390,5.117503"
"204655_at,6.650665,5.961215,4.502137,6.302132,8.173459,5.963574,5.593448,8.654259,7.012104,7.699193,8.975441,9.081770,6.199953,7.092247,9.388275,8.785206,5.236517,6.538903,5.542901,8.381781,7.285328,7.758906,7.306840,7.359977,5.560892,7.241452,6.510188,6.714308,7.363926,7.074580,5.692673,6.403216,6.557037,7.598483,7.064324,7.755842,7.687809,7.235367,5.219403,7.496645,7.190152,6.688152,9.468485,6.991092,5.542230,6.313225,7.614373,7.814979,6.595716,5.921920,8.832513,4.794072,8.976031,8.561321,7.713583,5.508850,8.438366,8.038440,6.839014,6.204068,7.471161,7.434325,8.815445,7.630331,7.144330,6.477527,7.332506,6.962909,7.415869,7.512550,7.016962,7.718584,6.959843,7.841404,6.001597,6.811345,6.037210,7.037965,7.516275,7.061561,6.843173,6.893718,8.027573,6.632176,5.624219,6.251045,7.047511,8.182857,9.332017,8.039766,7.028375,7.593977,8.053367,7.364296,6.966177,8.259199,7.174789,7.286412,7.605856,7.463830,8.965276,7.255868,8.114813,7.822935,7.777868,7.734489,7.768828,9.315155,8.463391,8.207845,8.243579,8.912486,7.023231,6.206887,7.919284,8.257003,6.499889,8.887293,8.399951,7.699658,7.801441,7.360122,8.516605,8.650405,7.336313,7.467414,6.771181,7.332684,8.511542,6.899943,10.21426,8.932474,9.326413,9.339486,7.308780,8.993833,8.908147,8.478899,9.854339,8.860277,7.700106,8.964482,6.538669,7.983135,8.265414,8.855818,9.138643,8.686069,6.718950,7.096758,8.378335,7.929211,9.492477,7.453168,7.287920,9.056026,9.443067,6.707054,6.222710,7.735581,6.969486,9.580289,9.728525,9.546083,10.57794,7.474049,9.345626,8.016472,5.770012,11.34314,10.04684,7.877441,9.610767,6.474897,11.49429,6.416017,8.783111,9.969609,10.65940,8.398946,8.407736,7.083379,9.913488,8.754452,5.849150,7.408506,11.89422,9.441239,6.476942,9.886713,10.85209,9.343652,10.47898,7.218926,9.793217,7.742909,11.66041,7.292561,6.548608,7.414166,8.289258,6.670037,6.940543,8.758918,7.851857,7.345621,7.588678,9.311652,9.574048,10.81287,7.100968,9.032301,7.138636,8.216857,8.676291,11.33970,7.652678,8.236510,9.097110,8.702020,10.82931,7.723108,9.661322,7.465699,9.038610,9.728005,5.556275,10.17158,8.457651,6.387838,8.129716,7.785093,6.856056,11.25984,5.208138,7.205551,9.351631,7.472090,8.560100,6.917197,9.680563,7.077901,7.499877,7.733567,8.627685,9.059433,8.699474,9.963902,8.886752,8.129716,6.572620,6.963223,3.830744,3.604445,3.813575,4.543612,4.582386,4.334254,3.771028,4.288163,4.339538,4.189198,4.439938,5.114137,5.682908,4.753696,5.840181,4.501900,4.011496,5.444103,4.493626,3.734620,4.112952,3.927328,5.163203,5.924691,5.567909,5.666916,5.708866,5.773158,4.988223,4.734517,4.051501,4.140079,3.779642,4.562665,4.596085,4.651792,4.250198,4.965583,4.975683,4.405568,4.474475,4.550982,4.426916,4.310027"
"1405_i_at,4.599676,5.356294,2.902536,5.894694,7.896798,5.683208,3.693357,8.285409,6.479218,8.226262,8.496574,8.220813,6.507729,6.375871,9.043485,7.647009,3.441790,4.460335,5.034970,8.037349,6.815930,6.503717,7.376199,4.771260,3.161119,5.408987,5.475976,5.518551,6.892761,7.515921,3.489281,6.827540,7.093593,6.911564,7.196808,7.427188,5.518241,5.035442,4.881056,6.518617,7.252580,6.626207,9.242115,6.168941,5.576531,5.616965,5.835012,7.034084,6.770410,3.521759,8.863164,2.985059,8.821679,8.546739,6.837130,3.300951,8.410931,7.681839,7.803553,5.734984,7.932826,7.713262,8.308675,7.059521,7.177021,6.499768,5.829755,5.534428,6.280709,6.527007,6.230461,8.042526,6.555088,8.036078,4.118279,5.079335,4.688174,4.612850,5.584097,5.795800,4.134113,5.398835,7.349036,5.759852,3.853642,4.886969,5.713067,7.597313,8.370106,6.654228,5.099130,7.344128,8.364515,7.265915,7.621372,7.695847,6.673858,7.225880,7.402362,7.348774,9.051883,5.992544,6.922981,7.923025,8.193292,6.093729,6.085431,8.930842,7.392228,7.924234,7.223278,7.892058,4.629742,4.336727,6.734394,7.746289,6.431290,8.060350,7.938584,7.795903,8.096038,7.696071,8.195568,8.653560,7.222156,6.293117,5.487318,5.083163,8.042590,6.387247,9.247022,7.990045,8.527196,9.029517,6.715796,9.349496,8.889863,8.625638,9.051151,8.913740,5.724819,8.105797,4.131332,6.676884,8.106372,8.874842,9.412777,8.917826,4.770090,7.573945,8.630658,8.027060,9.606805,7.836757,6.654189,8.547730,9.500316,6.108896,4.098463,6.577948,7.087371,9.141823,9.972382,9.147229,10.31933,7.106247,9.416912,7.494665,5.680458,11.48328,9.820821,7.731811,9.517542,5.894858,10.81487,5.824906,9.071822,10.08832,9.891550,8.635446,8.454205,6.096474,8.708048,8.748310,6.269855,7.622334,11.76967,9.128353,5.539459,9.281204,11.06934,9.028996,9.844261,7.585218,8.943382,8.380330,11.63562,7.270984,6.344478,7.594537,7.174577,4.264520,6.912699,8.157447,8.256793,7.111047,7.281751,9.354995,9.720663,11.16481,7.270010,8.847143,7.062869,8.404660,8.631271,10.81338,7.274801,7.885710,9.211394,9.349408,10.86465,7.690372,9.628380,7.516959,8.251977,9.757341,4.755844,10.45122,8.226947,6.770506,8.270787,7.659480,6.581373,10.80529,5.782499,7.877809,9.431764,7.762795,8.929886,7.146064,9.474732,7.372657,7.121184,7.876557,8.042947,9.059387,8.608525,9.763976,8.881587,8.270787,6.322104,6.920877,1.980104,2.946800,2.315635,2.665076,3.921116,3.290250,3.088347,2.387547,2.423701,2.387166,3.067863,3.928404,4.362160,3.915732,4.722498,3.717603,3.150708,2.870763,2.778725,2.271120,2.208967,2.600295,5.211226,5.749569,5.468895,4.965396,6.107967,5.814134,4.356696,3.833903,2.367238,2.548021,2.412447,2.651955,2.759190,2.892072,2.504659,3.212846,3.796741,2.755456,2.982593,2.922780,3.457164,3.078523"
```

How do I have the user export this data by downloading a file with a click of a button?
I have created a button which calls a function already, I just need to know how to create the file, write to it, and let the user download it.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is similar to the questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server/3665147#3665147) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107956/client-side-file-creation-and-download).

It seems like the most straight-forward solution (that only works on modern browsers) is to use [data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

[This answer to first question I shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197341/2134824) has a nice way of doing it. Then I assume you just hook up a button or a link to fire the `download` function.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me out big time!